# RPI Touchscreen turns off in solenoid circuit

Tags: raspberry-pi, solenoid

I have built a medical instrument that has an issue with a RPi touchscreen.
The circuit config is as follows:

- 24v 6A power supply
- 12V an 5V regulators
- Large 24V solenoid (https://www.mecalectro.com/produit/8-23-01-85/) connected to 24V supply
- Small 12V solenoid (https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Adafruit%20PDFs/412_Web.pdf) connected to 12V reg
- Humidifier circuit (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001346254830.html) connected to 5V reg
- RPi 4 connected to 5V reg. Touchscreen (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD_(H)) connected to RPi via USB and HDMI
- MOSFETs used to control activation of solenoids from RPi signal. Kickback diodes used.

Process is:

- Sprayer and small solenoid activated and deactivated momentarily before large solenoid is activated.
- When the large solenoid is activated the screen powers off and stays off.
- The issue doesn't occur using a standard monitor over HDMI
- The issue still occurs when the touchscreen is powered from its own source
- The issue doesn't occur when the RPi is powered using its own separate source.

I want to be able to use the 24V supply to power the whole circuit. Any suggestions of how to overcome the issue of screen depowering?
Thanks

Comment: how is the standard monitor powered? ... sounds like either, the power supply cannot supply the required current without a voltage dip or the solenoid is generating voltage spikes or both ... do you have a diode in parallel with the solenoid? ... have you measured the power supply voltage?

Comment: The standard monitor is just a pc monitor so it has it's own power supply. Yes there is a diode in parallel with the solenoid. The power supply voltage was measured as 24.2V